# Adjusting opacity of boxplot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, alpha

I'm wanting to adjust the opacity of these boxplots so that their overlap doesn't disguise the difference the 2 datasets.
[Boxplot Version 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWQMQ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWQMQ.png)

I thought alpha= was the ggplot2 syntax for adjusting opacity levels but when I enter the code like this:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_boxplot(data = W1_NO_TREE, aes(x= DISTANCE, y= DETRITIVORE_ALL, alpha= 0.5),
               varwidth = TRUE, fill = "blue")+
  geom_boxplot(data = W1_TREE, aes(x= DISTANCE, y= DETRITIVORE_ALL, alpha= 0.5),
               varwidth = TRUE, fill = "orange")+
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=20, face="bold", hjust = 0.5),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size=18),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size=18),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=13),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=13),
        legend.text = element_text(size=12),
        legend.title = element_text(size=15),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size=12),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Rem", "20m", "200m")) +
  scale_y_continuous('Abundance', expand=c(0,0), limits=c(-1,100),breaks=c(0,25,50,75,100)) +
  labs(title = "Pre-Treatment Detritivore Abundance",
       x="Distance",
       y="Abundance")
```

Then I get this outcome: [Boxplot Version 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PF0Sc.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PF0Sc.png)

I thought perhaps my error was putting alpha in aes() so I then tried:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_boxplot(data = W1_NO_TREE, aes(x= DISTANCE, y= DETRITIVORE_ALL), alpha= 0.5,
               varwidth = TRUE, fill = "blue")+
  geom_boxplot(data = W1_TREE, aes(x= DISTANCE, y= DETRITIVORE_ALL), alpha= 0.5,
               varwidth = TRUE, fill = "orange")+
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=20, face="bold", hjust = 0.5),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size=18),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size=18),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=13),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=13),
        legend.text = element_text(size=12),
        legend.title = element_text(size=15),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size=12),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Rem", "20m", "200m")) +
  scale_y_continuous('Abundance', expand=c(0,0), limits=c(-1,100),breaks=c(0,25,50,75,100)) +
  labs(title = "Pre-Treatment Detritivore Abundance",
       x="Distance",
       y="Abundance")
```

And got this outcome: [Boxplot Version 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlZsb.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlZsb.png)

I don't understand what the issue is as I've used alpha to adjust opacity in other graphs before. Does it simply not apply in boxplots? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Both options look fine. As you see from the images when adding alpha you get muted fill colors and mix of blue and orange where the bp overlap. However, instead of using opacity have you considered putting the bp side by side so that they do not overlap?

Comment: I'm not sure what else you are wanting to do with applying alpha, it seems to be showing exactly what you say you want: two boxes overlaid on one another which are then visible through each other. The issue is that the result isn't very intuitive, so I would echo Stefan and suggest plotting them side by side in pairs rather than overlaid. 

I often find the R graph gallery a useful source of inspiration and guides on how to present data well: https://r-graph-gallery.com/265-grouped-boxplot-with-ggplot2.html

Comment: @stefan yes side by side is a much better idea, just wasn't sure how to achieve that!

Comment: @KSkoczek thank you for the link! I wasn't sure how to do side by side plots, that link showed the syntax and I've got some much nicer looking graphs now :D